# Get specific field values from Get-Webbinding command in Powershell 2

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0

I am invoking a command :

```
$a = Invoke-Command -Computername $system -Scriptblock {import-module WebAdministration;Get-Webbinding}
```

The result that I am getting is something like this:

```
protocol             : http
bindingInformation   : *****
isDsMapperEnabled    : False
certificateHash      : 
certificateStoreName : 
ItemXPath            : /system.applicationHost/sites/s............
PSComputerName       : qwrqwrr
RunspaceId           : qweqwrqwrqwr
PSShowComputerName   : True
Attributes           : {Microsoft.IIs........}
ChildElements        : {}
ElementTagName       : binding
Methods              : {Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.........}
Schema               : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementSchema

protocol             : https
bindingInformation   : ******
isDsMapperEnabled    : False
certificateHash      : sdfghjkjhgfdsdfghgfdsasdfg
certificateStoreName : My
ItemXPath            : /system.applicationHost/sites/s............
PSComputerName       : qwrqwrr
RunspaceId           : qweqwrqwrqwr
PSShowComputerName   : True
Attributes           : {Microsoft.IIs........}
ChildElements        : {}
ElementTagName       : binding
Methods              : {Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.........}
Schema               : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementSchema
```

now I am trying to capture values under the fields protocol, bindingInformation, certificateHash etc and use them some where else. the way I tried was 
`$a.protocol` which is not working so if anyone can help me out here as I am new to powershell.
I want to capture the values from the variable $a which i created.

Comment: What do you mean with "is not working"? What output do you get from `$a.protocol`?

Comment: I am not getting any output with this command @Paxz. Can you please help me out here?

Comment: To me it looks like text information you can't get more information out of than you see. Check with `$a|Get-Member`